# resizing the background color of a form

Tags: html, forms, resize

if you try my code below you can see that the background color is light blue and it occupies the whole page of a site, I want to resize it how can you do that? I mean that the color will fit to the same size where the fill up boxes are, 
do i need to add this code: width="60%" 
can you please tell me where can I add this? Thanks

```
       <html>
       <div style="color:red">[+validationmessage+]</div>
       <p style="color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold">« You can subscribe here: »</p>
       <p>[+MailChimp.message+]</p>
       <div style="background-color:#CCDFED"> 
       <form method="post" action="[~[*id*]~]">

       <br/>
       <table>
       <tr>    
       <td><label style="margin:0.5em"> Email: </label></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="mc_EMAIL" size="60" 
    maxlength="60"  style="margin:0.1em" value="" /></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
    <td><label style="margin:0.5em"> Name: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mc_FNAME" size="60" 
    maxlength="60" style="margin:0.1em" value="" /></td> 
    </tr>  


    <tr>
    <td><label style="margin:0.5em"> Last Name: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mc_LNAME" size="60" 
    maxlength="60" style="margin:0.1em" value="" /></td> 
    </tr>     

    <tr>
    <td><label style="margin:0.5em"> Website: </label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mc_URL" size="60" maxlength="60" 
    style="margin:0.1em" value="" /></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
    <td><label style="margin:0.5em"> </label></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="subscribe" size="60" 
    maxlength="60" value="Register" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
    </form> 
    <p><br/></p>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="[~[*id*]~]" style="display:inline-block;background-color:#CCDFEF">
```

Remove the `<div style="background-color:#CCDFED">` before the form and `</div>` after it.

Comment: If you want a fixed width, you can remove `display:inline-block;` and replace it by: `width:123px;`.